# Typescript addEventListener implementation

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to re-create JQuery for training.

```
class $ {
  private element: HTMLElement;
  constructor(selector: string, parent: Document | HTMLElement = document) {
    this.element = parent.querySelector(selector);
  }
  color(cssColor: string) {
    this.element.style.color = cssColor;
    return this;
  }
  on(event: string, callback: Function | EventListenerObject) {
    this.element.addEventListener(event, callback);
    return this;
  }
}

const btn = new $("button").color("red").on("click", () => console.log("hi"));
```

TypeScript is complaining about the `on` method, it's saying:

> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 2, '(type: "input" | "progress" | "select" | "fullscreenchange" | "fullscreenerror" | "abort" | "animationcancel" | "animationend" | "animationiteration" | "animationstart" | "auxclick" | ... 80 more ... | "paste", listener: (this: HTMLElement, ev: Event | ... 13 more ... | ClipboardEvent) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void', gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"input" | "progress" | "select" | "fullscreenchange" | "fullscreenerror" | "abort" | "animationcancel" | "animationend" | "animationiteration" | "animationstart" | "auxclick" | ... 80 more ... | "paste"'.
> Overload 2 of 2, '(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void', gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'Function | EventListenerObject' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
> Type 'Function' is not assignable to type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
> Property 'handleEvent' is missing in type 'Function' but required in type 'EventListenerObject'.ts(2769)
> lib.dom.d.ts(5344, 5): 'handleEvent' is declared here.

**I have two questions:**

1- How it is possible for me to memorize all of the types of HTML elements?! there are a billion types, it's not just the .addEventListener() there is much more method on HTML element in JavaScript, **How am I going to get the benefit of typeScript with those?!**

2- How to fix the problem in my code?

Comment: Your callback needs to be of type `EventListenerOrEventListenerObject`

Comment: @Reyno, How did you know that? that's the central point in my question

Comment: I remove the type from `callback` (i think setting it to `any` also works) and then hover over the word `addEventListener` my IDE then shows the type it is supposed to be. I think the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) also does this.

Comment: I still need more help, I've completed a TypeScript course and I'm struggling too much with it, only because of this missed information